# Is there a frontface-visibility option in CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transforms

CSS/JS beginner here, I'm following a [webkit 3d-transforms](https://webkit.org/blog-files/3d-transforms/morphing-cubes.html) guide and trying to apply a hidden front-face option for the ring-rotation part:

[image: rotating-ring]

The "backfaces-visible" checkbox hides/shows the backface, could the opposite be implemented where the backface is visible and the front is hidden?

**Edit**:
With respect to the first comment, I'd like to clarify that the desired result should look like this (front planes are hidden while rotating):
[image]
(Front panels were erased with photo-editing, the rest are CSS changes. Mind the poorly edited left card)

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if this is what you are looking for, but If you don't use the `backface-visiblity` parameter at all, i.e. leave it at its default "visible" and if it has a non-transparent background, the backside will always cover the frontside, if its z-index or order in the HTML code is set that way.

My snippet below is derived from some older code I had at hand, in case you wonder. Press the button below the circle to trigger a turning animation.

```js
function turn1() {
  $('#front').css({transform: 'rotateY(180deg)'});
  $('#back').css({transform: 'rotateY(360deg)'}).delay(2000).promise().then(turn2);
};
function turn2() {
  $('#front').css({transform: 'rotateY(0deg)'}); 
  $('#back').css({transform: 'rotateY(180deg)'}).delay(2000).promise().then(turn1); 
};


$('#go').on('click', turn1);
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 180px; 
  height: 180px;
  font-size: 36px;
  perspective: 150px;
}
#front, #back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: transform 2s;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
#front { 
  background: green; 
}
#back { 
  background: yellow; 
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.x {
  text-align: center;
} 
button {
  padding: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="front">Front</div>
  <div id="back">Back</div>
</div>
<div class="x"><button id="go">Press to rotate</button></div>
```

If you add `backface-visibility: hidden` to the otherwise unchanged code, you see both sides when rotating:

```js
function turn1() {
  $('#front').css({transform: 'rotateY(180deg)'});
  $('#back').css({transform: 'rotateY(360deg)'}).delay(2000).promise().then(turn2);
};
function turn2() {
  $('#front').css({transform: 'rotateY(0deg)'}); 
  $('#back').css({transform: 'rotateY(180deg)'}).delay(2000).promise().then(turn1); 
};


$('#go').on('click', turn1);
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 180px; 
  height: 180px;
  font-size: 36px;
  perspective: 150px;
}
#front, #back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: transform 2s;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
#front { 
  background: green; 
}
#back { 
  background: yellow; 
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.x {
  text-align: center;
} 
button {
  padding: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="front">Front</div>
  <div id="back">Back</div>
</div>
<div class="x"><button id="go">Press to rotate</button></div>
```